# how to create scrollview animation elastic on react native cross platform

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I looked in several places and I didn't find anything like what I was looking for, if you have any ideas that can help me I am grateful, even if it is a line of research so I can follow and search on, thanks in advance.

EDIT

Posting code as requested, I just tried to add the bounce effect, but without success on android phones.

```
    <ScrollView 
        bounces={true}
        alwaysBounceHorizontal={true}
        alwaysBounceVertical={true}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        horizontal={true}>
            {lista.map((item) => {
                let ativada = item.ativo;
                if (!ativada) {
                    return (
                        <Card key={item.key} onPress={() => ToggleCard(item.key)} activeOpacity={0.7}>
                            <Icon name="filter-alt" size={25} color={PrimaryColor} />
                            <CardText>{item.title}</CardText>
                        </Card>
                    );
                } else {
                    return (
                        <CardAtiva key={item.key} onPress={() => ToggleCard(item.key)} activeOpacity={0.7}>
                            <Icon name="filter-alt" size={25} color={PrimaryColor} />
                            <CardText>{item.title}</CardText>
                        </CardAtiva>
                    );
                }
            })}
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Remove or Edit your post, some SO experts ( sarcastic ) will come in few minutes & start downvoting! provide some code that has been done, they like to see that to not downvote :)

Comment: @TaouBen done friend